# File level access permission in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have my TFS server and it has multiple branch like Dev,Test, UAT and Main. my problem is I have some security concern regarding web.config resides under Main branch. I want so access mechanism using which I can apply access permission on single file only.

I need that my team lead can only able to see that web.config file resides into Main branch but my developers can't see it.

how is this possible using TFS 2013?

Comment: Yeah, it works!!

Comment: Glad to here it. You could mark my answer as accepted, just click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Which will also helps other in the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this could be achieved. The simplest way is through source control explorer, select the file in Main branch from source control explorer and right click it, choose **security**.

[image]

On the pop-up dialog, you could be able to change the related permissions of this single file `xxx.config`.

[image]

In TFS **deny trumps allow**, then simply change the **read** permission for the group of developers  from allow to deny.

Comment: For me, it didn't work. I have this team project that has like 500 files in it, and I only want to give read permission to one single file to a TFS group. I followed your recipe, and gave read permission to `SinlgeFileReaders` group for `$\TempProjectA\FileToBeShared.java` file. Then I logged into VSTS (now Azure DevOps) in web browser using credentials of a given developer that is in `SingleFileReaders` group, and I don't see the `TeamProjectA`.